# Entity containing a ManyToOne Object that has 2 Primary Keys

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I've run into an issue that I'm not really sure how to implement. I'm trying to implement a web based audio recorder. Currently I have 3 Entities for this part. `Book` `Page` and `Recording`

each page maps to a book like so:

```
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bookID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $bookID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="pageNumber", type="integer")
     */
    protected $pageNumber;
```

what I'm stuck on is that each page can have multiple recordings, and I'm not sure if each recording needs to map to a book as well because each page is already mapped to a book.

```
class Recording
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="recordingID",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */

    protected $recordingID;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pageID", referencedColumnName="pageNumber")
     */
    protected $pageID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to map the recordings to the corresponding book entity because it will inherit this relation from its mapping to the page entity. If you have a recording entity and you would want to retrieve its book entity, you would be able to do something along the lines of

```
$oRecording = $this->_em->find($recording_id);
$oBook = $oRecording->getPage()->getBook();
```

In the database you should get for the page table

id    |  page_number | book_id
----------------
1     |  3           |12
2     |  4           |15

And in the recording table

id    |  page_id
----------------
1     |  2
2     |  2

So recording 2 has page_id = 2 and therefore book_id 15. In this way you do not duplicate data in your database.

Comment: but how will it be stored in the database? just curious, because with the page table, the BookID and PageNumber are primary keys.

Comment: Problem with that is as of right now, my page table can be like this, pagenumber 1, book id 12, pagenumber 1, book id 15.

Comment: ah I understand now, the easiest (and better I think) solution to that is by making the pagenumber not the primary key of a page entity, but rather use a meaningless identifier and create a separate protected variable for the page_number. I updated the databasescheme.